# Why only first item from list created with jQuery is sent through Ajax

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I have a list that I created with jQuery as follows:

```
        pros=[];
        cons=[];
        $.each($(".pro-item"), function(){
            pros.push($(this).html())
        })
        $.each($(".con-item"), function(){
            cons.push($(this).html())
        })
```

Now I want to pass it to server for processing, so I use Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        data: {
            pros: pros,
            cons: cons,
        },
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        url: '/pro_con_list',
        success: function(data){
            console.log("Ajax call successful")
        }
})
```

But when server(flask/python) receives it and I print the resulting data as such:

```
pros = request.form.get("pros")
print(pros)
print(request.form.get("cons"))
```

It only prints the first item of the JS list that was sent. I console.log both pros and cons lists and it   shows full lists:

```
(3) ["foo", "foo bar", "foo bar buz"]
(3) ["buz", "buz bar", "buz bar foo"]
```

And this is what python prints it received:

```
foo
buz
```

I assume I am not sending the the list properly, but the seemed to be the only way working and not printing None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `request.form.getlist("pros")`

To tease that out of the documentation, start at https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.form and drill down through `ImmutableMultiDict` to `MultiDict`, which is where most of the methods that `form` responds to are documented.